# iPhone simulator app crashes when appending a string

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsstring

I'm a complete novice, so I'm probably missing something really easy, but I can't get my string appending to work. I add the 3rd character to typedDigit & it crashes - the method is called fine and typedDigit will get to 2 characters long. I think everything is declared properly in the header file. Code is -

```
-(IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *digit = [[sender titleLabel] text]; // in this case, "0" - "9"

    if (userIsInMiddleOfTyping) {   // typedDigit is already at least 1 character long
        typedDigit = [typedDigit stringByAppendingString:digit];
    } else {                        // first character of typedDigit
        typedDigit = digit;
        userIsInMiddleOfTyping = YES;
    }

}
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the stack trace of the crash, it's hard to know the cause, but my guess will be that `typedDigit` is being autoreleased before the next call of your `digitPressed` function. `stringByAppendingString:` returns an autoreleased object, so you'll need to `retain` it if you want it to hand around past the next autorelease pool flush. For a direct fix, try something like...

```
if (userIsInMiddleOfTyping) {
  typedDigit = [[[typedDigit autorelease] stringByAppendingString:digit] retain];
} else {  
  typedDigit = [digit retain];
  ...
```

More than this, you'll need to make sure you `release` typedDigit at some point after the typing is over, and you're finished with it.

Comment: Thanks very much everyone, very grateful for such useful & prompt replies. Got it sorted by adding the necessary "retains", works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make sure digit is not `NULL` when trying to appending it. Also there is no mention of `typedDigit`'s initialization, so if it is a garbage pointer or otherwise poorly-initialized, you'll crash when you try to manipulate it.

Comment: A null `typedDigit` is unlikely to be a problem, as messages to null objects are silently discarded in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have an ownership problem.  If typeDigit is an object instance variable, you should be setting it with a setter method. In any case, you never call "retain" on the strings you want to keep around, so they are probably deallocated behind your back between method calls.